# Can every symmetric function be written as some function of a sum?

Tags: symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

I am looking for a simple counter-example to a "theorem" about symmetric functions claimed in a published paper.
The claim asserts, among many other things, that there are functions $\sigma$ and $\rho$ such that, for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$,
$$ \max(x,y) = \sigma(\rho(x) + \rho(y)). $$
The paper doesn't specify the domain of $\sigma$, which is, of course, also the range of $\rho$. I'll denote this unknown by $G$. And let's assume that $G$ is some well-known type of mathematical object, in which addition is conventionally defined, for example an abelian semigroup.

Can $\sigma$ and $\rho$ be found, if $G$ is an abelian (semi-)group? What if $X$ is a set and $G = \mathbb R^X$ is the set of functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$?

Actually, since real numbers can't be handled by a Turing machine, and the journal in which the paper appears is devoted to computer science, I would prefer a discussion in which the reals were replaced throughout the passage above by the integers. I expect the claim to be incorrect for any reasonable (non-finite) context.

If the reals are replaced by a finite closed interval of real numbers then any continuous symmetric function can be approximated by a symmetric polynomial, and then one can use Newton's identities to get an approximate result. Possibly this is what the author of the paper at issue was thinking, but not stating.

Comment: It would be helpful if you cited the paper you are talking about. Please do it.

Comment: "Actually, since real numbers can't be handled by a Turing machine" Computable real numbers can, by definition, be handled by a Turing machine. If real numbers are constructed as Dedekind cuts, we can represent a real number with a TM that, for each rational numbers, gives an output as to whether that number is less than the real numbers.

Comment: @Acccumulation: It is undecidable whether an arbitrary computable number is greater than an arbitrary rational number. For example, take the computable number to have (integer part zero and) an nth digit (after the decimal) of 1 if $2n$ is a counterexample to the Goldbach conjecture, and otherwise an nth digit of 0. Then take the rational number to be zero. Not only is that inequality undecidable, it's not even known to current mathematics.

Comment: @Kevin I don't see how that's undecidable, and if it were undecidable, I don't see how that number would be computable. And your last sentence is weird, as it implies that being unknown to current mathematics is stronger than being undecidable. And as for your first sentence, are you saying that it's undecidable whether all computable numbers are greater than an arbitrary rational numbers, or are you saying that there is a computable number for which it is undecidable?

Comment: @Acccumulation: I'm saying, if I give you an arbitrary computable number (in the form of a Turing machine that spits out the nth digit) and an arbitrary rational number (in the form of two integers in whatever encoding you like), then there does not exist a Turing machine which, for all possible pairs of one computable number and one rational number, decides which is larger. The example I gave was intended to be intuitively "easy" to understand, but you can replace "if $2n$ is a counterexample to the Goldbach conjecture" with "if Turing machine M halts in exactly n steps" instead 1/2.

Comment: This gives you a computable function that transforms Turing machines into computable numbers, such that f(M) = 0 if and only if M never halts. Deciding whether M halts is exactly equivalent to deciding whether f(M) is equal to zero. You can compute the nth digit of f(M) by simulating M for n steps, so f is a computable function and f(M) is a computable number (there is no requirement that we be able to compute a number "all at once," only that we can compute each digit individually). 2/2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll answer your question for $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Let $r(x,y) = p(x) + p(y)$. Your question boils down to whether there exists $p$ such that $r$ is injective up to symmetry.

Since $\mathbb{R}$ has uncountable dimension over $\mathbb{Q}$, there exists for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ some $t_x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the set $\{t_x \}_x$ is linearly independent. Set $p(x) = t_x$, so $r$ is injective and therefore there exists a $\sigma$ as desired.

(This uses the axiom of choice.)

Edit: I guess, it also uses the continuum hypothesis. I'm guessing there should be a proof avoiding some of these?

Edit 2: As pointed out in the comments, CH is not needed.

Comment: This solution also seems to work  in greater generality, which is very nice. Namely, let $X$ be any set whose cardinal is no greater than the continuum, and allow any symmetric real valued function of any finite number of variables, each in $X$.

Comment: The dimension of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathfrak c=2^{\aleph_0}$. See: https://mathoverflow.net/a/23206 . No CH needed.

Comment: Indeed, as @StinkingBishop says, this has nothing to do with CH. All you need is the observation that the dimension of the reals over $\mathbf Q$ is the same as the cardinality, and that is straightforward in pure ZFC (or even ZF+existence of a basis of $\bf R$ over $\bf Q$, I guess).

Answer (score 6):

For integers: Let $ρ(x) = 2^x$ for every integer $x$. Then given $ρ(x)+ρ(y)$ you can look at the binary form to determine $x,y$ and hence their maximum.

Answer (score 1):

A more concrete version of the idea from [user21820's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3800589/16078), for the situation where the domain of discourse is the integers:

Define $\rho(x) = 4^x$, and define $\sigma(t) = \lfloor \log_4 t\rfloor$, where $\log_4$ is the base-4 logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for integers generalizes to a constructive solution for real numbers, as follows.

To define $\rho$, first apply some constructive strictly-increasing map to reduce to the case where all our numbers are between $0$ and $1$. One such transformation is $x' = \frac12 + \frac1\pi \arctan x$.

Then, given a value $x' \in (0,1)$, write down sequence of zeroes and ones:

- A block of length $3$ in which the $\lceil 2x'\rceil^{\text{th}}$ bit is a $1$, and the others are $0$.
- A block of length $4$ in which the $\lceil 3x'\rceil^{\text{th}}$ bit is a $1$, and the others are $0$.
- A block of length $5$ in which the $\lceil 4x'\rceil^{\text{th}}$ bit is a $1$, and the others are $0$.
- And so on. In general, for each $n$, a block of length $n+1$ in which the $\lceil nx'\rceil^{\text{th}}$ bit is a $1$, and the others are $0$. Note that the last bit in each block is $0$.

Then, take $\rho(x) \in (0,1)$ to be the number whose binary expansion is this sequence.

Given $\rho(x) + \rho(y)$, we can find $\max\{x,y\}$ as follows. The sum of the blocks of length $n+1$ tells us $2^{\lceil nx'\rceil} + 2^{\lceil ny'\rceil}$, from which we can deduce $\lceil nx'\rceil$ and $\lceil ny'\rceil$ up to permutation. We can figure this out for arbitrarily large $n$, which gives us a sequence of arbitrarily good approximations to $x'$ and $y'$, from which $x$ and $y$ can also be found.

Comment: I don't doubt that you have a solution, but I can't understand your description, and it looks different from [mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3801424/21820). Can you be more precise?

Comment: @user21820 Can you be more precise about what you don't understand?

Comment: It just does not make sense. What does "its" in "its binary expansion" mean? What do the bullet-points mean? Why don't you give a mathematically precise definition?

Comment: Is this better? My definition is mathematically precise; I have just avoided using obscure notation like you have.

Comment: The convention in English is that a pronoun like "its" refers to the most recent mentioned noun that it could refer to. For example, when you write "It does not make sense", I assume that you mean "my answer", even though I want it to mean "your nitpicking".

Comment: No, it was not precise; bullet-points usually indicate that they are cases, whereas numbered points are usually used for sequences. and **no**, "its" does not always refer to the most recent noun. It may refer earlier, which is why it was ambiguous. After your clarification, I now can figure out what you mean, so it's better.

Comment: @Qi Zhu's answer (the first of these illuminating answers) generalises to any countable domain X ={x_n} and to an arbitrary symmetric function of a finite number of variables in X: because square roots of prime numbers are linearly independent over the rationals (http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51638.html). Let \rho(x_n) = \sqrt{p_n}, Then we can recover the argument of the symmetric function from the value of \rho(x_1)+...+\rho(x_n). Then define \sigma on that result.

Comment: @MishaLavrov and user21820 : I don't know much set theory, but is there really a constructive answer for computable real numbers? The problem I see is in determining max(x,y), when x=y, because the process of comparison goes on for ever. This is OK if the same Turing machine is used to construct x and y. The question of whether two Turing machines generate the same computable number sounds as though it's undecidable.

Comment: @DavidEpstein When $x$ and $y$ are computable, $\max(x,y)$ is computable, even if the answer to "which of $x$ or $y$ is larger?" is not. We just need to be able to keep outputting digits of $\max(x,y)$ one at a time, which isn't any more complicated when $x=y$: for as long as $x$ and $y$ have the same digit, we output that digit.

Comment: @DavidEpstein: This has nothing to do with set theory. As Misha already said, maximum is computable (i.e. a digit oracle for the maximum is computable from digit oracles of the given inputs). I'm not sure why you seem reluctant to accept the possibility. (Also, note that I did not get notified by your message because I was not `@`pinged.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov: By the way, I didn't notice earlier that you had removed the zero padding. Although the unordered pair of inputs should be recoverable (I am sure but didn't check), it seems a bit messy when there is 'overflow'; you need to go to sufficiently high $n$ to remove that overflow. Might as well just pad with zeros... And since we're talking about encoding, why not use a more easily computable encoding into $(0,1)$?

Comment: @user21820 You're right on both counts that the answer could be improved, but since it works and I'm not convinced the improved version would be interesting to anyone in particular, I'm not inclined to mess with it further. But if it bothers you to see my answer without those improvements, feel free to go ahead and edit it.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: I understand that, and thanks for the permission; I will edit it now (just in case a future reader gets confused about those points), but please let me know if you object to it!

Answer (score 1):

For reals: Let $d(x,k) = \lfloor x·2^k \rfloor$ for every $x∈ℝ$ and natural $k$. Let $ρ(x) = \{ ⟨k,2^{d(x,k)}⟩ : k∈ℕ \}$ for every $x∈ℝ$. Then $ρ(x)$ represents a unique sequence from $ℕ$ for each $x∈ℝ$. Define addition on sequences from $ℕ$ to be pointwise addition. Then for any $x,y∈ℝ$, we can determine $z = \max(x,y)$ from $ρ(x)+ρ(y)$ as follows.

We can easily obtain $S(k) = \{d(x,k),d(y,k)\}$ for each $k∈ℕ$. And $d(z,k) = \max(d(x,k),d(y,k))$ for every $k∈ℕ$. To see why, note that: (1) for any $m∈ℕ$ we have that if $d(x,m) > d(y,m)$ then $d(x,k) > d(y,k)$ for every $k∈ℕ_{>m}$ as well; (2) if $x > y $ then $d(x,m) > d(y,m)$ for some $m∈ℕ$. Therefore we can obtain $z$ since it is uniquely determined by $\{ ⟨k,d(z,k)⟩ : k∈ℕ \}$.

This is completely constructive (each of the desired functions are computable where each input or output $x$ is given as an oracle for $d(x,•)$).